# Strange POSIXlt year result

Tags: r, date

When I write

```
x <- c('2007-05-05', '2006-12-31')
strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d")$year
```

I get the result

```
[1] 107 106
```

I thought that POSIXlt started at 1970, but this appears to start at 1900?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html) says

```
POSIXct
```

represents the (signed) number of seconds since the beginning of 1970 (in the UTC time zone) as a numeric vector.

```
POSIXlt
```

is a named list of vectors  and the year means: years since 1900